# How to pattern match a generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to detect whether a type matches a certain Type pattern.  The pattern in this case is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, where T can match any type (the standard interpretation).

Given this pattern,

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> v;  //matches
Expression<string> v;  //doesn't match    
Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> v;  //doesn't match
```

My strategy is compare whether the beginning of the FullName of the test type matches the FullName of a generic type.  If it does, peels a layer off via GetGenericArguments, then repeat the check.  Code of the first check:

```
Type testType;

Type firstCheck = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<>);
bool isExpression = testType.FullName.StartsWith(firstCheck.FullName);
```

This seems to work, but rather ugly.  Moreover, it is not a generic solution; each pattern requires its own checker function.  Does anyone have a better solution?

A related question is how to best express a pattern?

Comment: Please don't put tags in your titles.  A comprehensive tagging system is provided for this purpose, and the most highly-used tag is already prepended to the title of your question for Google searches.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, won't happen again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
Type testType;

Type firstCheck = typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<>);
bool isExpression = 
    (testType.IsGenericType && testType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == firstCheck)
    || (!testType.IsGenericType && testType == firstCheck);
```

***Update***

Here is a recurrence method to check if type match given pattern:

```
private static bool IsTypeCompatibile(Type pattern, Type test, Type placeholder)
{
    if (pattern == test || pattern == placeholder)
        return true;

    if(pattern.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (!test.IsGenericType || pattern.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != test.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            return false;

        var patternGenericTypes = pattern.GetGenericArguments();
        var testGenericTypes = test.GetGenericArguments();

        return patternGenericTypes.Length == testGenericTypes.Length
            && patternGenericTypes.Zip(testGenericTypes, (p, t) => IsTypeCompatibile(p, t, placeholder)).All(x => x);

    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var pattern = typeof(Expression<Func<Placeholder, bool>>);

var type1 = typeof(Expression<Func<string, bool>>);
var type2 = typeof(Expression<string>);
var type3 = typeof(Expression<Func<string, string, bool>>);

Console.WriteLine(IsTypeCompatibile(pattern, type1, typeof(Placeholder)));
Console.WriteLine(IsTypeCompatibile(pattern, type2, typeof(Placeholder)));
Console.WriteLine(IsTypeCompatibile(pattern, type3, typeof(Placeholder)));
```

Prints

```
True
False
False
```

Of course, you need to define `Placeholder` class:

```
public class Placeholder
{ }
```

Comment: Is a generic solution possible at all, meaning the pattern itself will be passed to the checker as a parameter.

Comment: You'd have to create your own *placeholder* class and replace `T` with that class. Then you can use recurrence calls for each generic type argument type.

Comment: Not sure, maybe create an Expression?  But that seems even more complicated than creating individual checkers.

Comment: @CandyChiu I've updated my answer with the method you're looking for.